# How fast do lipids on the inside and outside of a lipid bilayer exchange?

Tags: cell-membrane, lipids

Biological membranes normally have different composition of lipids on the inside and outside ([ref 1](https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD%3A_Biophysics_241_-_Membrane_Biology/02%3A_Membranes_-_Aggregated_Lipids/2.02%3A_Membrane_Asymmetry), [ref 2](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/comments/S0960-9822(18)30009-5)).  This is maintained both by how new lipids are added to membranes, and by specialized enzymes ([flippases](https://moosmosis.org/2019/08/05/cell-membrane-dynamics-flippase-floppase-and-scramblase/)).  Certain lipids being on the "wrong side" is an important signal (eg for apoptosis).

My question is: how fast do lipids from the inside and outside exchange *spontaneously*?  In a patch of membrane with no enzymes, how long until half the "inside" lipids have flipped to the outside and vice versa through simple diffusion?

I did a search but couldn't find any specific paper that measures the spontaneous exchange rate.  I'd be very interested in a definitive answer - could be just order of magnitude, but based on real measurements.

**UPDATE** This is important for figuring out the inside/outside composition of membranes in real scenarios when they're no longer being maintained in an asymmetric state: for example enveloped viruses, but also microparticles, dead cells, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursory search seems to show at least a few papers using sum-frequency vibrational spectroscopy to measure rates of flip-flopping/transverse diffusion in lipid bilayers.

This [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349505728939) in particular ("1,2-Diacyl-Phosphatidylcholine Flip-Flop Measured Directly by Sum-Frequency Vibrational Spectroscopy") cites an activation barrier of 79 kJ/mol which corresponds to a rate on the order of 10^-4/s.

There is also this review which seems to have more information on the topic: http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.accounts.6b00435.

Comment: Very well. Also, this paper may be helpful, as it has some data about the activity of Mdr2, a phosphatidylcholine flippase by the measurement of time and relative fluorescence . One may also find the rate of movement implicitly .   https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0092867494904464                                       @Spencer Guo by the way, the first link of yours is not working.

Comment: @SpencerGuo - Good stuff, thanks.  From the first paper, looks like at human body temperature the half lifes are < 1 min for DMPC, 9 min for DPPC, > 300 min for DSPC.  Very dependent on lipid tail length...  The review is also excellent.

Comment: @AlexI Yes I should have noted that the barriers are quite strongly lipid identity-dependent.